# inserting data to influxdb by nifi is too slow

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

I have data pipeline in NiFi , which listen to system log and process received data and extract attributes by "ExtractText" processors Then make influx input format by "ReplaceText" and at the end insert to influxdb by "PutInflux" processor. But I get a long queue before putInflux processor because insert speed is too slower than produced data. Please help me to increase insert speed. 
[Data PipeLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFAzR.png)

[ReplaceText processor configuration : (view_stat -> measurement , Listing_id -> tag, event_id -> value , Timestamp -> time )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bizsd.png)

[PutInflux processor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3lXt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Are you putting multiple lines into Influx at once (i.e. multiple lines in a flow file) or one line at a time? If the latter, try a MergeContent or MergeRecord before PutInfluxDB, to get multiple lines into a file. Then you won't have to pay the overhead of transmitting each line over the wire, you can put a lot of them at once.